# sql exception: inconsistent datatypes: expected TIMESTAMP got NUMBER

Tags: java, sql, oracle

i have created a coloumn in sql database with timestamp database.
and from java i am trying to run insert query given below

```
st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
st.executeUpdate("insert into profmessage values('" + uid + "','" + from + "','" + to + "','" + msg + "','" + dt + "',1,0,'" + new java.sql.Timestamp(new Date().getTime()) + "')");
st.close();
```

It is showing

```
sqlexception  inconsistent datatypes: expected TIMESTAMP got NUMBER
```

Comment: First thing to first: *don't put values into SQL like that*. Use a prepared statement. Next, specify the columns in your insert statement, to avoid it being schema-order-specific. Fix both of those issues, then see if it still doesn't work.

Comment: can you say `SQL injection`?

Comment: your issue must be related to columns ordering, use column name in insert statement also as suggested by Jon you should use prepared statement

Comment: @coreJavare u r right. I was wrong woth coloumn order. Nut now it is giving exception as ORA-01843: not a valid month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use PreparedStatement (which is also good for avoiding SQL injections), and insert the value of timestamp like this:

```
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(theNumberOfTimestampOccurenceInYourQery, new java.sql.Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, the `TIMESTAMP` data type doesn't mean what you think it means. `TIMESTAMP` columns are meant to be updated by the server itself as it creates and updates rows. Their values look like "`0x00000000001CF9F9`", which is really just a number in hexadecimal format.

What you need is the `DATETIME` data type.

Comment: The `ORA-01843` error code mentioned in the comments suggests they're not using SQL Server.

Comment: This is Oracle, not SQL Server... Yeah, never mind my answer, it's not applicable. I'll leave it up in case someone else googles the problem, but in the future, I would use better question tagging!